# How to find extreme points on mesh in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have an `.obj` file(it has vertex and faces). I put it under `Assets` folder.

I create an empty `gameObject`. I drag the prefab(.obj file) to the gameObject. GameObject inspector view is :

[image]

How can I get extreme points from this object? (upperLeft, upperRight, lowerLeft and lowerRight)

I tried `collider.bounds.size` but it is not real mesh size(it draw a box around mesh).

Answer (score 2):

```
 Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
 Vector3 [] vertices = mesh.vertices;
```

Then iterate to find extreme x and y and store the vertices containing them.

Comment: You are right. But it depends how to add model to scene. GameObject doesn't has a MeshFilter my scene. I add MeshFilter and drag .obj file to it. It works now.